# Why Dataflow FlexRS batch job run twice in a row producing duplicate results?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have apache beam flex template with the flexRS options [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs#pipeline_options) running in Google Cloud and is triggered by GCF.

My simplified code looks like this:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

raw_data = (p
            | 'Create input data' >> beam.Create([known_args.input_path])
            | 'Read input data' >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
        )

json_data = (raw_data | 'load json' >> beam.ParDo(LoadJsonFn()).with_outputs('failed', main='passed_data'))
cleaned_data = (json_data.passed_data | 'few transformations' >> beam.ParDo(EtlFn()).with_outputs('failed', main='passed_data'))

merged_failed = ((
    json_data.failed,
    cleaned_data.failed
) | 'Merge failed data' >> beam.Flatten())

(merged_failed | 'Save failed data' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.failed_output_path))

(cleaned_data.passed_data 
                | 'Dump to json' >> beam.Map(lambda e: json.dumps(e))
                | 'Save transformed data' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output_path))

p.run()
```

Simply it reads data from Cloud Storage, does some transformations and outputs to Cloud Storage.

My problem is that it saves the passed data to my output path twice creating duplicates. When looking at the job metrics, there are two spikes in the graph suggesting that the job ran twice in a row after being on pause in between.

[image: two executions]

[image: sink]

Would anyone know what is causing this behavior and how to avoid it so I don't need to manually delete the duplicates from my sink?

Update:
Found this [article](https://medium.com/@dev.vasugupta/understanding-duplicates-in-google-dataflow-with-apache-beam-e47bb0a9587b) which suggests that it is due to the data shuffling. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you know if the data itself is being duplicated or if it's just being split between the files? For example, would a single output element appear twice, once in each file, or would it only appear once in one of the files?

Comment: Single element from this job would appear once in each '00015' ending files and once in each '00018' ending files. So the issue is that the pipeline outputs duplicate datasets, only the number of files is different.

Comment: Hmm. That tells me that the issue is probably not data shuffling. If the problem was shuffling, you'd be likely to see elements only in one or the other file, since each element only gets sent to one worker. More likely this is an error in the pipeline. Are json_data and cleaned_data supposed to both read from raw_data? That might cause elements to appear in both the failed and successful outputs. Do you use windows or triggers in the full pipeline? I could see something like this happening due to windowing.

Comment: @DanielOliveira Sorry there occurred a typo - cleaned_data reads from json_data.passed collection. As per windowing, no there's no windowing or aggregations in this pipeline. It is a simple batch job just transforming a dataset for further consumption.

Comment: This seems to be a bug on dataflow when FlexRS is used with flex templates only. Will be fixed soon and will update this thread once fixed.

Comment: @ArvindRam Thanks for confirming!